# OrderBy deletes object property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code:

```
var test = _fitDbContext.MvLatestTestResult
        .Include(r => r.LastTest)
        .Include(r => r.LastTest.Testrun)
        .Include(r => r.LastTest.Testrunconfig)
        .Where(r => r.LastTest.Testrunconfig.Started.Value.Hour >= 0 && r.LastTest.Testrunconfig.Started.Value.Hour < 6)
        .Where(r => r.LastTest.Testrun.Userc == "build")
        .Where(r => r.ProductId == productId)
        .GroupBy(r => r.LastTest.Testrunconfig.Started.Value.Date)
        .OrderByDescending(r => r.Key.Date)
        .Take(3)
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.GroupBy(r => r.Configfilename));
```

Variable `test` looks like this:

[image]

You can see that `LastTest` is `null`. If I remove `.OrderByDescending(r => r.Key.Date)`, it contains value.

Why does **OrderByDescending** remove LastTest value?

---

**EDIT**

Interesting thing I just found out. If I change order of `GroupBy` and `OrderBy`, everything works as expected. The problem is that `OrderBy` is executed with all records and takes a long time.

```
var test = _fitDbContext.MvLatestTestResult
        .Include(r => r.LastTest)
        .Include(r => r.LastTest.Testrun)
        .Include(r => r.LastTest.Testrunconfig)
        .Where(r => r.LastTest.Testrunconfig.Started.Value.Hour >= 0 && r.LastTest.Testrunconfig.Started.Value.Hour < 6)
        .Where(r => r.LastTest.Testrun.Userc == "build")
        .Where(r => r.ProductId == productId)
        .OrderByDescending(r => r.Key.Date)
        .GroupBy(r => r.LastTest.Testrunconfig.Started.Value.Date)
        .Take(3)
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.GroupBy(r => r.Configfilename));
```

Comment: Are you *sure* it's the `OrderBy` that is stripping off the `Include`?  In my experience, it would be the `GroupBy`, since anything that acts as a projection will have that effect.

Comment: The simple solution would be to trigger the query after `.Where(r => r.ProductId == productId)`, with `.ToList()` or `ToListAsync()`.

Comment: Both of you pointed me in the right direction. The problem is that calling `.ToList()` fetches more than 100.000+ rows which slows the application dramatically. Any other options?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I edited my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Note: since you `GroupBy` `.Date`, you can just `OrderBy` `.Key`.

Comment: Can you re-add the `Include`s after the `Take`?